# Where do I initialize a local git repository for WebStorm?

Tags: git, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Where do I initialize a local git repository for [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/specials/webstorm/webstorm.html)? Should it be the same or different folder from workspace?

I'm newbie with WebStorm and want to add my project to local git repository.

My question is where to initialize it? Can it be same folder as workspace or it must be different folder, like in Eclipse for example, the last one is preferable solution by me.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to do it with the command line.

Go to your directory:

`cd your_directory`

then init a new one:

`git init`

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/

After that Webstorm recognize it and will ask you if you want to add the new root to your project.

Comment: You mean go to my workspace directory? And what does root mean?

Comment: You "root" mean in that case your project folder. Yes go to that directory you want your git location in and run the comment. Then you have a new one and you can checkin your files. Then your git repo is a local one. In most cases its better to create an repo on bitbucket for example an declare it as private. Then you have a backup.